# Gradient Colors with ngStyle in ion-card

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an ion-card repeated in page each time it display take different color base on array from classlist.page.ts so instead of using normal colors I want to use this gradient color

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #ff8008, #ff930d, #ffa619, #ffb727, #ffc837);
background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #1d976c, #40af7f, #5cc792, #78e0a5, #93f9b9);
background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #eb3349, #ee3f47, #f04946, #f25344, #f45c43);
```

**classlist.page.html**

```
<ion-card
*ngFor="let course of classes"
class="cards-description"
[ngStyle]="{'background': course.backgroundColor}"
(click)="openClassStudents(course)"
>
</ion-card>
```

**classlist.page.ts**

```
@member classBackgroundColor used for background color of class

classBackgroundColor = [
    "#ff7043",
    "#2962ff",
    "#43a047",
    "#6d4c41",
    "#ffab00",
    "#00b0ff",
    "#651fff",
    "#2962ff",
    "#d81b60",
    "#6a1b9a",
  ];

if (courses && courses.length > 0) {
            let i = 0;
            this.classes = courses;
            this.reorderList = [];
            this.classes.forEach((course) => {
              course.backgroundColor = this.classBackgroundColor[i];
              i++;
              if (i == 9) i = 0;
            });
          } else {
            this.noDataFound = this.lang.no_class_found;
            this.classes = [];
            this.reorderList = [];
          }
```

Comment: So this is homework you got from class and you want us to tell you how to do it?

Comment: None, my own app developed by another developer and i want to start learning how i can modify it in order to improve UI Design since i can not offer to hire another developer to do this